# How should we handle questions/answers about temporal service issues

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

This came up during a LQP review that I marked OK (and was subsequently deleted by a mod).

Review link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24035399

Screenshot of the answer for <10k users:

> [image]

Question link: [How to fix firebase Deployment error - retries exhausted after 6 attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911367/how-to-fix-firebase-deployment-error-retries-exhausted-after-6-attempts)

Firebase hosting was giving errors yesterday which (probably) caused the user's issue (haven't validated it, but seems likely). Someone answered "hey their server has an issue, here's the incidence ticket," which I thought was OK at the time, but marginal (it's little more than a link answer).

I was going to flag the question itself as cannot be reproduced, but it technically COULD be reproduced, if firebase hosting ever gets screwy again.

So.... what should I have done? Should I have marked that question as OK? Should I have flagged that question as cannot be repro?

Note I'm asking both sides:

- What should we do about questions where the answer is "the service has a temporary issue"? Although it's possible that the same situation might happen in the future, by definition, it's a localized issue.
- What *could* make an answer acceptable here?  At best, it's going to be a link saying "yep, stuff is/was broke right now" (the answer given). At worst, it would be a one-line answer just saying "lol samzies edit: works now." (which I'd definitely vote/flag delete). I'm assuming there's no workarounds (like connect to server B when A is down; go to downtime procedures etc).

Finding that answer in the LQP review queue is somewhat inconsequential. This wasn't a review audit or anything, and I can see why it was deleted.

Comment: The question itself *can* be useful, but that specific answer isn't. If it was reworded and specified that it could happen when the server is down (and specifying that's the problem in this case), it's a general answer instead of a specific answer, and is slightly more useful in the future. It also opens the answer for alternative solutions where the server isn't the problem. (That being said, this could still be a dupe - I haven't looked)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense to me to delete an answer like this. If the cause of the problem asked about in a question is a temporary service outage, then, well, that's the answer. Maybe it's a reason to nuke the *question*, but not the answer, surely? My take is that you did the right thing and this shouldn't've been deleted.

Comment: The answer has since been converted to a comment by a different mod.

Comment: The problem isn't the answer, is the question. If the question instead becomes "Under which circumstances `retries exhausted after X attempts` failure happens?", that would be a useful question for future readers.